# Parsing / Scraping a table using Python, Urllib from an FTP site

Tags: python, parsing, ftp, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse / scrape some data from an FTP site. Specifically: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA_000513335.1_PCAMFM013_20131106

Eventually I would like to be able to have a Python script that will download all the files from this site. But first, i'm trying to learn how to get all the download links using BeautifulSoup4 and urllib2. (Since requests doesn't work with HTML sites?)

I inspected the elements and see they are stored in a table, however I get an attribute error for findAll when i call it.

This is what my code looks like right now (still starting. I want to mess around with the table data):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA_000513335.1_PCAMFM013_20131106"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr') <== error here

print rows
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Am i approaching this incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It cannot use `findAll` on a `None` object because `table` contains nothing. `table` contains nothing because `soup.find('table')` did not return anything. `soup.find('table')` returned nothing because your `soup` variable only contains a huge `<p>` statement. Print out `soup` and see.

Comment: Yeah I see now. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML table is not sent by the FTP server. Only the browser will  generate the HTML based on the directory listing returned by the FTP server. This means you can not use BeautifulSoup to parse it. Instead look into [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) for interacting with FTP servers.